# Invoke-WebRequest doesn't return control

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, invoke-command

I have a SharePoint root site called `http://myserver`

When I try to access this site using `Invoke-WebRequest` powershell command then it doesn't return the control. It keeps on running until I press Ctrl + break to stop execution.

```
Invoke-WebRequest "http://myserver" -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing
```

When I open that site in browser then it quickly opens so that means site is not an issue.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue but the resolution here is not working - I can see there are trackers on the web page and some take up to 30 seconds ore more in the browser debug tools to complete, but Invoke-WebRequest never returns control.   I've tried several mechanisms Like MaxRedirects, BasicParsing, and Methods but the Cmdlet never returns to the command prompt.  Browser page loads in just a second or so.

Answer (score 0):

I removed "UseBasicParcing" and added "URI" part and now it is working:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -URI "http://myserver" -UseDefaultCredentials
```